# Prometheus alert relabeling to apply fallback label

Tags: devops, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to configure prometheus to add a fallback label `team=devops` to the alert labels, when not provided by the alert rule.

Example of alert rule with `team` label:

```yaml
    - alert: CustomErrorRuleForTeamDev
      annotations:
        description: |
          This is a custom error for dev team
      expr: my_metric_total > 0
      labels:
        severity: error
        team: dev # <-- This label value should not be relabeled
```

Example of alert rule without `team` label:

```yaml
    - alert: CustomErrorRule
      annotations:
        description: |
          This is a custom error
      expr: my_metric_total > 0
      labels:
        severity: error
```

How should I configure the `alert_relabel_configs` to keep the label `team=dev` for `CustomErrorRuleForTeamDev` in the AlertManager and add the label `team=devops` where the label `team` is missing?

I've tried the following configuration, but it applied always `team=devops`:

```
alerting:
  alert_relabel_configs:
  - target_label: team
    replacement: devops
```

Comment: use regex to check for condition and then replace

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong - I want to add the label `teams=devops` only if this label does not exist yet. If I apply a regex I would overwrite the existing value `teams=dev` where it exists. I don't want to do a replacement, but apply a fallback value.